# Inner Join Query incorrect result

Tags: c#, sql, join, sql-server-ce, inner-join

Hi I am developing an application in VS 2010, C# and SQLCe database.

I am generating a report from 3 tables respectively Income, Expence and Transactions.

table structure is as below:

Income:

[image: Income]

Expence:

[image: expence]

Transactions:

[image: trans]

For this I wrote query

```
select t.tDate as [Date], t.tDescription as [Detail],e.eAmount as [Debit], 
i.iAmount as [Credit], t.balance as [Balance] 
from Transactions t 
   inner join Expence e on t.pid=e.pid 
   join Income i on t.pid=i.pid 
where t.pid='11'
```

But when I run this query I am just getting

[image: result]

I want that my result should be like a bank statement as below.
[image: final]

As per my understanding query is not right.

How can we write query to get result like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the `left join`, not use Join. Because `left` return all cases in table `from` and case exists in table Expence e Income.

```
select t.tDate as [Date], t.tDescription as [Detail],e.eAmount as [Debit], 
    i.iAmount as [Credit], t.balance as [Balance] 
 from Transactions t 
     left join Expence e on t.pid=e.pid 
     left join Income i on t.pid=i.pid 
 where t.pid='11'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right to join items from Expence table with items from Transactions table you should use pId and eId and to join items from Income you should use pId and iId, so your select would look something like that:

```
select t.tDate as [Date], t.tDescription as [Detail],e.eAmount as [Debit], 
i.iAmount as [Credit], t.balance as [Balance] 
from Transactions t 
   inner join Expence e on t.pid=e.pid and t.eId = e.eId
   join Income i on t.pid=i.pid and t.iId = i.iId
where t.pid='11'
```